# Does MySQL Lazy Union really work?

Tags: mysql, union, mysql-8.0

**Following query is an example of Lazy Union:**

```
SELECT GREATEST(@found := -1, userId) AS userId
FROM user WHERE userId = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT userId
FROM user WHERE userNumber = 1 AND @found IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE ( @found := NULL ) IS NOT NULL;
```

It means that if the first query in the `UNION` doesn't return any data then the second query will access data lazily. But when I check the MySQL Execution Plan it shows that this query still runs the second query of the UNION even if the first query returns data. In my query the first query of the UNION returns data.

**MySQL Execution Plan:**

[image]

What is wrong with this query? Did I mess up with MySQL's Lazy Union or something else?

**Following is my original query which work perfect:**

```
SELECT u.userId, u.userPassword, u.userStatus FROM user u WHERE userId = 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT u.userId, u.userPassword, u.userStatus FROM user u WHERE userNumber = 1;
```

Comment: What output did you get?  What output do you expect?  Are `userNumber` and `userId` different columns?  The last two `SELECTs` can probably be combined into a single one.

Comment: Expression evaluation order in UNION is not documented. In practice all UNION parts seems to be executed simultaneously. So user defined variable usage as made in your query is wrong and must give unpredictable result. In practice all 3 parts will be executed using NULL value for the variable, I think.

Comment: To obtain deterministic result in 8+ version you must: 1) move subqueries to separate CTEs 2) add UDV initialization into 1st subquery 3) perform UNION in main query or 4th CTE.

Comment: @RickJames i get my expected result, my result will be complete user table row for respective users, also the userId and userNumber are different column, with different data. The problem is that i have to search user existence by userId or userNumber. so thats why previously i used union all for using index userId and userNumber. that work well and also used indexs. Today after reading a book 'High Performance MySQL by Percona' i got this Lazy Union idea and applied it on my previous union.

Comment: @Akina actually previously i used union all for cover index userId and userNumber. That work well and also used indexes. Today after reading a book 'High Performance MySQL by Percona' i got this Lazy Union idea and applied it on my previous union. So from your comment it's seems that Lazy Union do't work now, maybe those was effective old version. If so than i think i do't need to worry about Lazy Union, i can stay with norma Union.

Comment: I agree with Rick James: why use a UNION in the original query to begin with? Why not a single query using  `where userid = 1 or usernumber = 1`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah that was my mistakes, i was following some old tutorial for SQL tuning that's why i used `union` for cover two index rather than using `or`. now after checking by `or` I found that MySQL automatically using union with both two rows, `union(Primary, userNumber)`. Thanks you both, Rick James and You.

Comment: @Rhidoy - MySQL rarely uses "Using index merge union", so the "old" `UNION` is still useful.  Note: Whereas `UNION ALL` is more efficient, you may get duplicate rows.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for point out that, so i may stick with two union. duplicate rows not the problem here because userId or userNumber is always unique. So there will not be more than 1 row.